# Storing Image from Local Directory to MongoDB in Meteor Application

Tags: javascript, image, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

Does anyone know how I can get images stored on a local folder into the MongoDB database of a Meteor application and then render those images on my page?

Comment: What you tried?? What you searched? Show your code!

Answer (score 0):

I use `lepozepo:s3` for this. It does not store it local, but it does store it to Amazon S3 which frankly, is better.

It's pretty easy, `meteor add lepozepo:s3`. And the documentation is very good: https://atmospherejs.com/lepozepo/s3

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain! I guess what I was wondering more of is whether or not we can just directly get an image on local directory into a Meteor's Mongo collection as opposed to having to upload the image through the page because I dont want to have that functionality on the final application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **CFS** Packages for storage the images in your mongodb:
https://atmospherejs.com/?q=cfs

In this article you can see how to do it:
https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/how-to-upload-files-with-meteor-js-7b8e811510fa#.37nva5dfz

If you want something for upload to an external bucket, you can use the **slingshot** package:
https://atmospherejs.com/edgee/slingshot

with this package, you can send your files from your app, to an amazon or google storage bucket.this package is very usefull and is a better choice if your application will storage many images.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain! I guess what I was wondering more of is whether or not we can just directly get an image on local directory into a Meteor's Mongo collection as opposed to having to upload the image through the page because I dont want to have that functionality on the final application.